# Cumulative subtraction between columns

Tags: r

I have 12 columns:

11 are "day0", "day1" ... "day10" from in a df called "forecasting"

1 is "within10closures" in a df called "headcount"

Both dfs are of the same length.

I want to subtract headcount$within10closures from forecasting$day10 unless it hits 0, in which case I want it to subtract the remainder from day9 and so on until it gets to day0.

at the moment I have the code below which - whilst long and probably not the most efficient way - seems to work but I want to do this same procedure with multiple sets of columns the vary in number. Hopefully it explains what i'm trying to do.

```
for(i in 1:i) if(forecasting$day10[i]>headcount$within10closures[i]){
  forecasting$day10[i] <- forecasting$day10[i] - headcount$within10closures[i]
} else {
  forecasting$day10[i] <- 0
  subtraction <- headcount$within10closures[i]-forecasting$day10[i]
  if(forecasting$day9[i]>subtraction){
    forecasting$day9[i] - (subtraction)
  } else {
    forecasting$day9[i] <- 0
    subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day9[i]
    if(forecasting$day8[i]>subtraction){
      forecasting$day8[i] - (subtraction)
    } else {
      forecasting$day8[i] <- 0
      subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day8[i]
      if(forecasting$day7[i]>subtraction){
        forecasting$day7[i] - (subtraction)
      } else {
        forecasting$day7[i] <- 0
        subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day7[i]
        if(forecasting$day6[i]>subtraction){
          forecasting$day6[i] - (subtraction)
        } else {
          forecasting$day6[i] <- 0
          subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day6[i]
          if(forecasting$day5[i]>subtraction){
            forecasting$day5[i] - (subtraction)
          } else {
            forecasting$day5[i] <- 0
            subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day5[i]
            if(forecasting$day4[i]>subtraction){
              forecasting$day4[i] - (subtraction)
            } else {
              forecasting$day4[i] <- 0
              subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day4[i]
              if(forecasting$day3[i]>subtraction){
                forecasting$day3[i] - (subtraction)
              } else {
                forecasting$day3[i] <- 0
                subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day3[i]
                if(forecasting$day2[i]>subtraction){
                  forecasting$day2[i] - (subtraction)
                } else {
                  forecasting$day2[i] <- 0
                  subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day2[i]
                  if(forecasting$day1[i]>subtraction){
                    forecasting$day1[i] - (subtraction)
                  } else {
                    forecasting$day2[i] <- 0
                    subtraction <- subtraction - forecasting$day2[i]
                    forecasting$day1 <- forecasting$day1 - subtraction
                  }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to create a for loop to do the same thing but where i can control which column ranges to to the subtraction on but I don't really know what i'm doing and it doesn't get the right numbers at all (apologies for the messy code):

```
for(x in 1:11){
    for(i in 1:n){
    ifelse(x==1, subtraction <- headcount$within10closures[i], subtraction <- (subtraction - (forecasting[i,grep("day10", colnames(forecasting))+1-x])))    
    ifelse(forecasting[i,grep("day10", colnames(forecasting))+1-x]>=subtraction, forecasting[i,grep("day10", colnames(forecasting))+1-x] <- forecasting[i,grep("day10", colnames(forecasting))+1-x] - subtraction, forecasting[i,grep("day10", colnames(forecasting))+1-x] <- 0)
    }    
  }
```

Essentially what I'm asking is how do I efficiently cumulatively subtract between columns based on another column's value whilst  controlling for the number of columns to subtract from?

---

Simplified input:
**forecasting:** (values could be any number)

```
day0 | day1 | day2 | day3    
-----+------+------+------
1    |  2   |  4   |  18
10   |  10  |  10  |  10
7    |  10  |  10  |  10
```

**headcount:** (values could be any number)

```
| within10closures |
        6
        10
        35
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
day0 | day1 | day2 | day3    
-----+------+------+------
1    |  2   |  4   |  12
10   |  10  |  10  |  0
2    |  0   |  0   |  0
```

**data**

```
forecasting <- data.frame(matrix(rep(10, 12), nrow = 3))
colnames(forcasting) <- paste0("day", 0:3)

headcount <- data.frame(within10closures = c(6, 10, 35))
```

---

**Edit:**
forecasting dataframe is not always all 10, consider below as example input:

```
set.seed(1)
forecasting <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 12, replace = TRUE), nrow = 3))
colnames(forecasting) <- paste0("day", 0:3)

#   day0 day1 day2 day3
# 1    3   10   10    1
# 2    4    3    7    3
# 3    6    9    7    2
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the input/output.  If you can put it in a format that others can just copy/paste into their R sessions it will make it easier for them to help you.

Comment: @zx8754 sorry just saw your question: if the last row was 45 instead then I want it to go into negatives (-5) on day0 (the last column selected for subtraction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reviewed after update:

datas:

```
set.seed(1234)
forecasting <- data.frame(
  day0=sample(1:10,4),
  day1=sample(1:10,4),
  day2=sample(1:10,4),
  day3=sample(1:10,4),
  day4=sample(1:10,4)
)
headcount <- data.frame(within10closures=c(6,10,25,12))

> print(forecasting)

  day0 day1 day2 day3 day4
1    2    9    7    3    3
2    6    6    5    9   10
3    5    1    6   10    2
4    8    2    4    6    8
```

Code:

```
for (i in 1:length(headcount$within10closures)) {
  v=headcount$within10closures[i]
  tmp <- c()

  if (sum(forecasting[i,]) - v < 0) {
    forecasting[i,] <- c(sum(forecasting[i,]) - v,rep(0,ncol(forecasting) - 1))
  } else {
    for (x in rev(forecasting[i,])) {
      tmp <- c(tmp, ifelse(x - v < 0, 0, x - v ))
      v <- ifelse(v - x < 1, 0, v - x)
    }

    forecasting[i,] <- rev(tmp)
  }
}
```

Basically a loop on the values to substract, if the value is greater than the row, build the row with a negative value as first element.
Else loop over the corresponding row reversed (`rev`) and do the difference, set to 0 if there's more to substract than the current value.
Then remove the value from what's is to remove, set it to 0 if it gets under 1 (0 or negative).
Finally reverse this built vector (`tmp`) and set in to replace original forecasting row.

This gives:

```
> forecasting
  day0 day1 day2 day3 day4
1    2    9    7    0    0
2    6    6    5    9    0
3   -1    0    0    0    0
4    8    2    4    2    0
```

---

Previous answer:

This seems to get what you're after , not handling negative number in this primary version, second version below:

```
forecasting <- data.frame(day0=rep(10,3),day1=rep(10,3),day2=rep(10,3),day3=rep(10,3))
headcount <- data.frame(within10closures=c(6,10,35))

nb <- rowSums(forecasting)-headcount$within10closures

result <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(nb, function(x) {
    c( 
      rep(10,x%/%10),
      ifelse(10-x%%10==10,0,10-x%%10),
      rep(0 , ( ncol(forecasting) - x%/%10 -1) ) 
    ) 
}
)))
colnames(result) <- paste0("day",1:ncol(forecasting))
```

first I compute the sums for each row, and I substract the corresponding `within10closures` value.

Now for each value (the `sapply` loop), I get the number of columns with full 10 (the plain division `x%/%10`), the remainder part and the number of columns at 0 to complete the row.

For the remainder (`x%%10`) we have two case, when it worth 0, wwe wish to display 0 and not 10, so there's this `ifelse` within the vector construction to set 0 if we get 0, or 10 minus the remainder if positive.

This give use a  matrix like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   10    5
[2,]   10   10    0
[3,]   10   10    0
[4,]    6    0    0
```

To make it back into a data.frame we need to transpose it `t( )` and coerce it to data.frame with `as.data.frame`, and final touch is naming the columns with `day1 to ncol(forecasting)` (could be from 0 to ncol(forcasting)-1 if needed with `0:(ncol(forecasting)-1)` , pay attention to the parentheses here to get the proper values, range is expended before the substraction happens).

To handle negative number we need some more conditions as `-5%%10` returns 5:

```
result <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(nb, function(x) {
    c( 
      rep(10,ifelse(x%/%10>-1, x%/%10, 0) ),
      ifelse(x%%10==0,0,ifelse(x >0, 10 - x%%10, x) ),
      rep(0 , ( ncol(forecasting) - ifelse( x%/%10 > -1, x%/%10, 0) - 1 ) ) 
    ) 
}
)))
```

Here there's an addition of ifelse on the primary division to get 0 or a positive number and drop negative numbers.
One more `ifelse` on the remainder to use it only if positive, if not we keep the negative value even if it's greater than 10. I.e: you may end up with a row like `-35 0 0 0`

Comment: Thanks I think I understand your approach, however wouldn't that rely on the forecasting values always being 10? I set 10 as all the original values just to clearly demonstrate what I was after but the values in the forecasting df could actually be any number. I ought to include this in the question too actually

Comment: @SaleemKhan as long as you wish block of 10 in the final result df, that will work.

Comment: But I think I see what you're after if the input was `6 5 3 4` and the within was 5 the result should be `6 5 2 0` right ?

Comment: Trickier but sounds doable (with a whole new approach, may you update the question ?)

Comment: If I can suggest a bit of an adjustment: in my actual datafram there are many more columns, some not being numeric and some that i dont want to include in the equations. If I replace forecasting[i,] with forecasting[i,grep("day0", colnames(forecasting)):grep("day10", colnames(forecasting))] so it allows me to mess with the range of columns depending on which set i want to use to calculate? Also ncols(forecasting) to ncols(forecasting[, grep("day0", colnames(forecasting)):grep("day10", colnames(forecasting))] - this would actually allow us to turn it into a function to use in the future

Comment: I'd go with a `grepl('day\\d+', colnames(forecasting))` to get only those columns. Try it, it should work

Comment: Also for ifelse(v - x < 1, 0, v - x): to account for potential decimals, would v-x <= 0 be more suitable?

Comment: You can if there's decimal, that's the problem when you don't make a exemple matching the reality, the answers are not exactly matching what you're after ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159698/discussion-between-saleem-khan-and-tensibai).